# is it possible to start R Studio Server on a port other than port 8787?

Tags: rstudio-server

I'm trying to start an instance of R Studio on my Linux server, but I already have 8787 dedicated to a running process and was wondering if there is a command line option to specify another port to run the R Studio server on?

not sure what options to add following
`rstudio-server start`

Comment: Find in the [docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj98Z_QsP2BAxW3gf0HHVYjA88QFnoECDAQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Frstudio-server%2Frstudio-server-pro-0.98.507-admin-guide.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2XA6JSCmB7GhQQfSOiuWuY&opi=89978449)  `www-port=80` (to modify the port number to 80),  which should be in the file: `/etc/rstudio/rserver.conf`